# JS loop only works when matching to the last element in an array

Tags: javascript

I cannot get the loop to work in my simple js login script. When i try to login with any login other than the last one in the array (user3 and pass3) it returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried both `==` and `===`.

```
var userLogins = [{user:"user1", password:"pass1"},{user:"user2", password:"pass2"},{user:"user3", password:"pass3"}]
var success = null;
function logon(user, pass) {
    userok = false;
    for (i = 0; i < userLogins.length; i++)
    { 
        if(pass == userLogins[i].password && user == userLogins[i].user )
        {
            success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    secret(success);
}

function getData() {
    var user = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    logon(user, password);
}

function secret(auth){
    if(auth)
    {
        show('success');
        hide('login');
    }
    else
    {
        show('error');
        hide('login');
    }
}

function show(show) {
    document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
}
function hide(hide) {
    document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to declare `i`, `for (var i = 0` otherwise trouble...

Comment: Please tell me this is for nothing that is secure!

Comment: Nope. its for an assignment. I would never use JS like this for anything secure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < userLogins.length; i++)
{ 
    if(pass == userLogins[i].password && user == userLogins[i].user )
    {
        success = true;
    }
    else
    {
        success = false;
    }
}
```

**You need a `break` in there**, otherwise your `true` value for `success` simply gets overwritten with `false` on the next iteration... except for the *last possible credentials*, for which there is no "next" iteration.

Once you've done that, you don't actually need the `else` branch at all:

```
var success = false;
for (i = 0; i < userLogins.length; i++) { 
    if (pass == userLogins[i].password && user == userLogins[i].user) {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `break` when you found it. Otherwise the next loop will set success to false.

```
for (var i = 0; i < userLogins.length; i++)
{ 
    if(pass == userLogins[i].password && user == userLogins[i].user )
    {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        success = false;
    }
}
secret(success);
```

Comment: Better yet, get rid of the else branch, set `success = false` at the beginning, and set success, call `secret`, and return out of the loop when you find a match

Comment: Simple! how did I not see that.